# Epireflective Subcategories and Closure under the formation of mono-sources

Tags: category-theory

In the paper "On relational spaces" by C. Se Hwa - Journal of the Korea Society of Mathematical Education, 1985, Vol. XXIV, no.1, the author shows that the category of posets is an epireflective subcategory of Rel, the category whose objects are pairs $(X,R)$, with $R$ a binary relation on $X$. The way of proving it is to show that $Pos$ is closed under the formation of mono-sources. I'm not sure of this. In fact, in general, let $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be complete, well-powered and co-well-powered: then $\mathcal{A}$ is epireflective in $\mathcal{B}$ if and only if $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under the formation of **extremal** mono-sources.

It is not true that Mono-sources in Rel are extremal, otherwise Rel would be a balanced category. So, why the author says that it suffices to show the closure under the formation of mono-sources? And secondly, I have no idea of how to construct a $Pos$-reflector of $Rel$. Can you help me, please?